# Creating database in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Can I create database using php code for free hosted/domain plans. (Hostinger).

If so what to write in `$db_name`

`$db_name = "profile";`  OR `$db_name = " cpannel username_profile";`

For `CREATE DATABASE $db_name`

I tried but it get connected. At the time creating database it says access denied.

`Could not create database: Access denied for user 'user'@'192.168.0.%' to database 'TUTORIALS'`

Comment: have you tried either? try it!

Comment: Tried, it gets connected but do not create database

Comment: What does the query `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'192.168.0.%'` return? Going to say you will not be able to accomplish your goal, due to the free hosting plan you're using limiting your permissions.

Answer (score 0):

from the error message, it looks like your user 'user' doesn't have privileges to create tables. have you granted him privileges to do that?

you didn't mention a database, but to grant most privileges to a user, you could do it like this in mysql:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,ALTER,INDEX ON *.* TO 'user'@'%'
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Is it to be written in `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @MKJain that is a MySQL query to grant user the permissions. Execute the statement at your MySQL server console or IDE while logged in as a user that has `GRANT` privilege.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **free** domains, they will **not allow** you to create the database with `PHP` as giving permission for that may result in deletion/addition of databases from other users too. For reference visit: https://forum.infinityfree.net/discussion/2158/access-denied#latest an answer by an admin of one of the free database provider!